# Bash how to print arguments starting with vowel and end in a digit

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am writing a script that prints arguments starting with a vowel and end in a digit

```
Example : ./script Alex1GB0 Bud1GG0 Ethan8DC0 Chad5XZ7d
```

The output should be

```
Alex1GB0 Ethan8DC0
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for x in $*; do
     o=$(echo $x | grep '\<[AEIOUaeiou]...[0-9].\>')

     if[$? -eq 0]; then
            echo $o
     fi
 done
 exit 0
```

It doesn't work ; What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like ellipsis (`...`) in bash. Instead, use `.*`. Also, the dot after `[0-9]` means there is something after the digit, which is against the specification.

In fact, there is no need to run a subshell and `grep`, when we have pattern matching:

```
#! /bin/bash
for x in "$@"; do
    if [[ $x == [AEIOUaeiou]*[0-9] ]] ; then
        echo "$x"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Works like a charm , it prints what I want!Thanks! I didn't have the slightest idea you could check a string like that, without sed, awk, grep.

Answer (score 1):

**grep**

```
grep -oP '(?<=\s)[AEIOUaeiou][^ ]*[0-9](?=\s)'
```

your example:

```
kent$  echo "Example : ./script Alex1GB0 Bud1GG0 Ethan8DC0 Chad5XZ7d"|grep -oP '(?<=\s)[AEIOUaeiou][^ ]*[0-9](?=\s)'
Alex1GB0
Ethan8DC0
```

**awk**

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^[AEIOUaeiou][^ ]*[0-9]$/)print $i}' file
```

your example:

```
kent$  echo "Example : ./script Alex1GB0 Bud1GG0 Ethan8DC0 Chad5XZ7d"|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^[AEIOUaeiou][^ ]*[0-9]$/)print $i}'
Alex1GB0
Ethan8DC0
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep in mind these examples, they will help me with similar scripts. What does (?<=\s) stand for (in grep), though?

Comment: \s means all blank characters. `(?<=abc)x` means match x, only if x is following abc. google look-behind.